# Global NSMutable array of a project

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to know how i can declare and use  a global NSMutable array of an Objective C project.
I mean i need to update the here in one class and need to use in another class....

can anyone give me any kind of idea??

Thanks
Rony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a reference around from class to class. Or keep a reference to the array instance in your app delegate, which you can access from any class in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the singleton pattern and put the array into the singleton.